# is it neccessary to specify '-D' while using npm install?

Tags: npm-install

for example, when I need to install webpack, usually we are supposed to use "npm i -D webpack", but if I use "npm i webpack" instead, there is no difference in my final bundle file, why we need to specify '-D'?

I think there is no differences between them, why not just use npm i?

```
npm i -D 
npm i
```

Comment: It depends partly what kind of package you're working on - it can be useful so that for example `npm audit --omit dev` only tells you about vulnerabilities in the code you're shipping; or an installation with `NODE_ENV=production` doesn't include all your dev dependencies; or consumers of your package only get the transitive dependencies needed at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs, `npm install -D` means you are installing the package as a devDependency and not a regular dependency.

##### How is this different?

When your app is deployed and your server runs the `npm install` step, it will only install the packages that are in dependency and not those in devDependency. Hence, we usually install things like `eslint`, `typescript` and such as devDependency and not regular depedency.

#### Reference

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install